# Tastypie: define authentication for all resources

Tags: python, django, tastypie

What is the best approach to define authentication/authorization for all tastypie resources? I have many resources and don't want to copy the authentication line every time. Right now, I defined a function

```py
def create_auth():
    return MultiAuthentication(ApiKeyAuthentication(), BasicAuthentication())
```

and am calling it in each resource' meta class:

```py
class SomeResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        authentication = create_auth()
```

Is there a better solution for this? Is a 'metametaclass' solution possible/better? E.g.

```py
class AuthMeta:
    authentication = MultiAuthentication(ApiKeyAuthentication(), BasicAuthentication())

class SomeResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta(AuthMeta):
        # further settings

class SomeOtherResourceNonORM(Resource):
    class Meta(AuthMeta):
        # further settings
```

Comment: I don't get it, you've already had base class `AuthMeta` and it's already been inherited by all `Resource`, what else are you looking for?

Comment: This is just another proposal that I came up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the `metametaclass` as recomended for both [tastypie](https://github.com/django-tastypie/django-tastypie/issues/98) and [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance).

```
classs YourBaseResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        authentication = MultiAuthentication(ApiKeyAuthentication(), BasicAuthentication())

class SomeResource(YourBaseResource):
    class Meta(YourBaseResource.Meta):
        # further settings

class SomeOtherResourceNonORM(YourBaseResource):
    class Meta(YourBaseResource.Meta):
        # further settings
```

**update:** using the correct base resource

Comment: That is a wrong answer because this gives an error
ModelResource (YourBaseResource) requires Meta.object_class or Meta.queryset

Comment: @UsamaAhmed the problem here was just the misuse of `metametaclass` reference, not what you mentioned, which is also correct